# (selenium+python): 'driver' is not defined. Did you mean: 'webdriver'?

Tags: python, class, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to check if a gmail id is already registered as an apple ID.
I did the solution using sequential programming and now trying to restructure it using class in python. I'm getting 'driver' is not defined issue although I already defined it. I am new to the concept of classes.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

class CheckRegistation:
    def __init__(self, mail):
        self.mail = mail
        options = ChromeOptions()
        # open and maximize the screen
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        # below 2 lines disables the info bar
        options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


    def check_email(self):

        driver.get("https://appleid.apple.com/account")
        email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="email"]')
        email.send_keys(self.mail)
        pwd = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        get_source = driver.page_source
        search_text = " This email address is not available. Choose a different address. "
        a = search_text in get_source
        if a == True:
            print("Please use a new email")
        else:
            print("You can use this email to sign in! ")

p1 = CheckRegistation("xyz@gmail.com")
p1.check_email()
```

Please help how can I fix it

Comment: Did you intend to make that an _attribute_, `self.driver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create the web driver object with self so that It can be shared across class methods

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

and in your "check_mail" method, replace the "driver" with "self.driver".

example:

```
self.driver.get("https://appleid.apple.com/account")
```

Answer (score 0):

*`driver`* should be an attribute, So essentially **`self.driver`** as:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every occurrence of "driver" in your class needs to be "self.driver" since it is an instance variable & then everything should work.